# php convert 1000 to 1,000.00

Tags: php, regex

I was wondering if there is any php function to convert the number of 1000 to 1,000.00, 10000 to 10,000.00 and so on . I can write a regex but I just want to know if there is any php build in function like floor .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see http://docs.php.net/number_format

```
for($e=1; $e<9; $e++) {
  echo number_format(pow(10,$e) , 2), "\n";
}
```

prints

```
10.00
100.00
1,000.00
10,000.00
100,000.00
1,000,000.00
10,000,000.00
100,000,000.00
```